# loading different container view from container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have 3(cv1, cv2, cv3) container views place on same position on mainViewContoller.

All 3 having different viewController classes (`.swift`)

Button is placed on cv2(secondViewController), on that button click I want to change containerView from cv2 to cv3.

For more clear, how can I call mainViewController method from secondViewController (cv2)?

secondViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {

   // Want to call action of firstViewController which is changeContainerView()

}
```

firstViewController.swift

```
funct changeContainerView(){
   loginContainerView.hidden = true
   signUpContainerView.hidden = false
}
```

Like that.

Comment: Please share the piece of code where you are stuck

Comment: @IdreesAshraf added code.

Comment: How are you adding these view controllers on your main view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `delegate` pattern. It's very common in the Cocoa framework. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks. As I am new to iOS development itself. I just wanted to know is it possible what I am expecting? I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                let svc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

                                self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            })
```

Yout need just change mainstoryboard name if it needed and name of destination VC in 2 places